# Perform SUBSTRING on a Pig Latin Command Parameter

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a pig script that is passed a command argument as part of oozie workflow, I want to create a new variable as a substring of the passed parameter.
eg:

```
%declare VAR1 SUBSTRING($INPUT, 0, 5);
```

The error is usually;
ParseException: Encountered "  "0, "" at line 5, column 37.
  Was expecting:
  < NEWLINE > ...

Apache Pig version 0.12.0-cdh5.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One feasible approach. Worth contemplating

**Pig Script :**

```
%declare REQUIRED `echo ABCDE | cut -c1-3`;
A = LOAD 'a.csv' USING  PigStorage(',')  AS (value:chararray);
B = FILTER A by value == '$REQUIRED';
DUMP B;
```

**Input : a.csv :**

```
ABC
XYZ
```

**Output : DUMP B :**

```
(ABC)
```

In the declare statement in place of ABCDE we can specify $INPUT.

```
%declare REQUIRED `echo $INPUT | cut -c1-3`;
```